# Filter column that other columns don't have only positive values and don't have only negative values

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Currently to make this filter I use this formula:

```
=FILTER(AC2:AC,
NOT((S2:S>0)*(T2:T>0)*(U2:U>0)*(V2:V>0)*(W2:W>0))*
NOT((S2:S<0)*(T2:T<0)*(U2:U<0)*(V2:V<0)*(W2:W<0))
)
```

I would like to know if there is a correct and more direct method for this same result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your title is a bit confusing, but from your formula my interpretation is that you are filtering out rows from column AC where  the corresponding row in columns S:W are all either positive or negative. You could try:

```
=filter(AC2:AC,byrow(S2:W,lambda(row,abs(sum(sign(row)))<>5)))
```

SIGN returns 1 for +ve numbers and -1 for -ves. We can get the ABS value of the SUM of SIGNs per row with BYROW, so it's simply a case of FILTERing by those rows not equal to 5 (only observed for all +ves or all -ves in a row).